# Google Map iOS SDK - clear all markers within and without visible region

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

So the `mapView.clear()` method only removes the markers from the map within a visible region where I currently idle at.

I can still see other markers on the map by zooming out or moving around the map. Those markers couldn't be removed cause they were invisible the time I invoked `clear()`.

My current solution is to loop through all markers stored in an array and invoke `marker.mapView = nil` to make sure each of them gets removed from the map.

Is there any other way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Every time that you add a marker in your `GMSMapView` you can keep it in an array, and after that when you want to remove all of them you only have to cycle over them making `.map = nil`

```
    for marker in self.markers {
        marker.map = nil
    }
    self.markers.removeAll()
```

This is what you can read from GoogleDocumentation about this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#eliminar_un_marcador

Comment: yeah that's the way I'm adopting rn, just wanna see if there's any official solution or so.

Comment: ok @devdork that is the way then, I hope that my answer help you in some way or another, best regards